# how to redirrect using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect every request of my site like this:

> http://www.example.com/four_digit_number

to

> http://www.example.com/index.php?m=four_digit_number

I already have a redirection rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^http://(www\.)?sipem.com
RewriteRule  ^([^\/]+\.jpg)$  /images/managers/$1  [L]
```

which in redirects visitors from

> www.example.com/four_digit_number.jpg

to

> www.example.com/images/managers/four_digit_number.jpg

I need to add this rule to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a new rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\d{4})/?$ /?m=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^http://(www\.)?sipem.com
RewriteRule  ^([^/]+\.jpg)$  /images/managers/$1  [L]
```